# "Too many files specified; only takes APK file and verifier file" problem

Tags: adb

I have some devices attached to my PC. Now I want to install Astro to a specific emulator. Unfortunately, I get this error.

```
hieund@hieund:~/Downloads$ adb install "Astro File Manager 2.5.1.apk" -s emulator-5554
too many files specified; only takes APK file and verifier file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generates this error when there is only an emulator attached.

```
EOCD not found, not Zip
file 'AstroFileManager2.5.1.apk' is not a valid zip file
```

I realized that the AstroFileManager apk has problem. **I downloaded a new one from xda and it works**.
Done.

Answer (score 3):

the -s  should be before the 'install'

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an whitespace problem in the filename. Either remove or escape them.

Comment: Have just tried it. Sorry it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, correct. If the path contains white spaces, then you will get this issue.